# How to correctly redirect_to @profile in a single line?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, methods, routes, refactoring

Having many checks in my controller like below:

```
if @profile.expired
  redirect_to profile_path(@profile.id)
  return
end
```

Would it be possible to refactor this to a single line?

```
Also if using this code it redirects to /profiles.28
```

where 28 is the id
How would one correctly redirect to

```
/profiles/show/28 or profiles/28 ?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most likely what you need:

```
redirect_to(profile_path(@profile.id)) if @profile.expired
```

You almost never (and by almost never, I mean effectively never) need `return` statements in your controller code. If you really need this for some reason, you can do

```
redirect_to(profile_path(@profile.id)) && return if @profile.expired
```

As for your other question, I'm guessing you incorrectly specified something in your routes, and if you posted them I'd be happy to correct them.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not fully clear about what you wanted to achieve but with my best guess, you can do it in a single line as follows:

```
(@profile.expired) ? (redirect_to profile_path(@profile.id) and return) : 'do something else'
```